# Why is a bending rod assumed to be undergoing torsion?

Tags: classical-mechanics

If I take a rod and bend it at both ends as far as it will go, why is there an assumption that I am also exerting a torsion along with my bending?

Referencee: ccording to the third edition of "Theory of Elasticity":

> "It is important to note that, when a rod undergoes larding
>   deflections, there is a general twisting of it as well, so that the
>   resulting deformation is a combination of pure bending and torsion."

Comment: What's the context? I've never heard of this assumption.

Comment: According to the third edition of "Theory of Elasticity": "It is important to note that, when a rod undergoes larding deflections, there is a general twisting of it as well, so that the resulting deformation is a combination of pure bending and torsion."

Comment: "Larding deflections"?  I think autocorrect may gotten to your answer;  what was the original text?

Comment: "Large deflections". Freaking Autocorrrect.

Answer (score 1):

Without further context I believe what the book is saying is that when one applies a pure bending moment stress in a beam that the resulting strain is not nessiarily purely in bending, but will also include torsional strain.

For example, if one looks purely at bending moments and assumes that no torsional strain will take place, then a C beam would be just as strong as an I beam. However, if one tried to use a single C beam in place on an I beam it will deflect tortionaly. If this deflection is significant then, the forces will no longer be aligned with the strong direction of the beam and it may cause buckling failure.